# Как найти координаты прямоугольного параллелепипеда

Tags: математика, матрицы, координаты

Как решить вот такую задачу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть координаты `baseCornerPoint` есть `height`, `length`, width

Нужно найти

1) Координаты лежащей по диагонали точки от `baseCornerPoint`

2) Центр этого параллелепипеда

Я знаю, что это материал школы, но это было давно.

P.S.

Я пытался решить эту задачу, просто не стал излагать все не верные решения тут.

Вот ссылки которые смотрел и пытался делать по ним

https://multiurok.ru/files/rasstoianiie-ot-tochki-do-ploskosti-mietod-koordin.html

[https://www.fxyz.ru/формулы_по_геометрии/формулы_объема/объем_параллелепипеда/](https://www.fxyz.ru/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0/)

https://ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=505871

Но чет не сильно получилось

Если кто то учиться сейчас то подскажите

Comment: То есть вы даже и не пытались сами решить эту задачу?

Comment: Все вроде тривиально, если он не повернут относительно осей

Comment: @AnT Дополнил вопрос

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну так напишите ответ или дайте ссылку где почитать

Comment: если не повернут относительно осей: `p2 = (p1.x - length, p1.y + width, p1.z + height)`, `pc = (p1.x/2+p2.x/2, p1.y/2+p2.y/2, p1.z/2+p2.z/2)`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Нахождение втрой точки по диагонали я тоже написал таким способом, но мне показалось, что должна быть какае то формула... А вот насчет нахождения центра не догадался, что можно так, спасибо

Comment: да пожалуйста, могу оформить как ответ...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ конечно. Я отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по изображению, вторая точка может быть найдена арифметически вот так

```
vec3 p2 = vec3(p1.x - length, p1.y + width, p1.z + height);
```

При этом центральная получается полусуммой координат начала и конца диагонали

```
vec3 pCenter = vec3((p1.x+p2.x)/2, (p1.y+p2.y)/2, (p1.z+p2.z)/2);
```